Problems with repositories updating ubuntu
I still cant solve the problem, because paths and filenames are not the same.
Hi im having these problems with sudo apt update in ubuntu 24.04.1
[sudo] contraseña para eduardo: 
Lo siento, pruebe otra vez.
[sudo] contraseña para eduardo: 
Obj:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Obj:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Obj:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease              
Obj:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease            
Obj:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease          
Obj:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/makehuman-official/makehuman-community/ubuntu noble InRelease
Obj:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu noble InRelease              
Obj:8 https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu any InRelease                   
Des:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease [7.468 B]
Des:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease [7.532 B]
Des:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease [7.462 B]
Des:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease [7.461 B]
Obj:13 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian noble InRelease        
Obj:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease              
Descargados 29,9 kB en 3s (11,1 kB/s)                  
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se pueden actualizar 17 paquetes. Ejecute «apt list --upgradable» para verlos.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key 36E81C9267FD1383FCC4490983FBA1751378B444 uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key B32DD95E55F948FDE700857027CDF84E4716DAB5 uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)
N: Omitiendo el uso del fichero configurado «contrib/binary-i386/Packages» ya que el repositorio «http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian noble InRelease» no admite la arquitectura «i386»
N: Omitiendo el uso del fichero configurado «main/binary-i386/Packages» ya que el repositorio «https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease» no admite la arquitectura «i386»
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/makehuman-official/makehuman-community/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code'

How can i solve them ? I have tried to add [ arch = amd64] in many repos but it doesnt work...im facing same problems....
eduardo@MiPcLinux:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -l
total 552
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   288 sep 19 22:53 canonical-kernel-team-ubuntu-proposed-jammy.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   212 ene 16  2024 canonical-kernel-team-ubuntu-proposed-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   123 nov  4 20:05 canonical-kernel-team-ubuntu-proposed-jammy.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   123 nov  4 20:05 canonical-kernel-team-ubuntu-proposed-jammy.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   131 sep 19 22:53 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    93 ene 16  2024 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   107 nov  4 20:05 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-focal.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   107 nov  4 20:05 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-focal.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   142 sep 19 22:53 danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-raring.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   104 ene 16  2024 danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-raring.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   126 nov  4 20:05 danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-raring.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   126 nov  4 20:05 danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-raring.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106 sep 19 22:53 gns3-ppa-trusty.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    68 ene 16  2024 gns3-ppa-trusty.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2618 nov  4 20:05 gns3-ppa-trusty.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2618 nov  4 20:05 gns3-ppa-trusty.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   122 sep 19 22:53 indicator-multiload-stable-daily-raring.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   122 ene 16  2024 indicator-multiload-stable-daily-raring.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   125 nov  4 20:05 indicator-multiload-stable-daily-raring.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   125 nov  4 20:05 indicator-multiload-stable-daily-raring.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    97 sep 19 22:53 jfi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    97 ene 16  2024 jfi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   101 nov  4 20:05 jfi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   101 nov  4 20:05 jfi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   120 sep 19 22:53 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    82 ene 16  2024 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    96 nov  4 20:05 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    96 nov  4 20:05 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    69 sep 19 22:53 linuxgndu-gajj-sci-trusty.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    69 ene 16  2024 linuxgndu-gajj-sci-trusty.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   695 nov  4 20:05 linuxgndu-gajj-sci-trusty.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   695 nov  4 20:05 linuxgndu-gajj-sci-trusty.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   127 sep 19 22:53 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    89 ene 16  2024 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   115 nov  4 20:05 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   115 nov  4 20:05 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   122 sep 19 22:53 makehuman-official-ubuntu-makehuman-community-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   122 ene 16  2024 makehuman-official-ubuntu-makehuman-community-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   119 nov  4 20:05 makehuman-official-ubuntu-makehuman-community-bionic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   119 nov  4 20:05 makehuman-official-ubuntu-makehuman-community-bionic.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    68 sep 19 22:53 medibuntu.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    68 ene 16  2024 medibuntu.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   108 sep 19 22:53 megasync.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   108 ene 16  2024 megasync.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   129 sep 19 22:53 microsoft-prod.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    81 sep  8  2022 microsoft-prod.list.dpkg-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    89 ene 16  2024 microsoft-prod.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7250 nov  4 20:05 microsoft-prod.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7250 nov  4 20:05 microsoft-prod.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   110 sep 19 22:53 mixxx-ubuntu-mixxx-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    72 ene 16  2024 mixxx-ubuntu-mixxx-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    92 nov  4 20:05 mixxx-ubuntu-mixxx-bionic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    92 nov  4 20:05 mixxx-ubuntu-mixxx-bionic.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   133 sep 19 22:53 mono-official-stable.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    95 ene 16  2024 mono-official-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   113 nov  4 20:05 mono-official-stable.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   113 nov  4 20:05 mono-official-stable.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   126 sep 19 22:53 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    88 ene 16  2024 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10138 nov  4 20:05 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10138 nov  4 20:05 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   760 sep 19 22:53 mysql.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   760 ene 16  2024 mysql.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 sep  3  2022 nginx-stable-trusty.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   202 sep 19 22:53 nodesource.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   202 ene 16  2024 nodesource.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   115 sep 19 22:53 noobslab-apps-raring.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   115 ene 16  2024 noobslab-apps-raring.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106 nov  4 20:05 noobslab-apps-raring.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106 nov  4 20:05 noobslab-apps-raring.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   114 sep 19 22:53 ppa_git_core_ppa_saucy.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    76 ene 16  2024 ppa_git_core_ppa_saucy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   105 nov  4 20:05 ppa_git_core_ppa_saucy.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   105 nov  4 20:05 ppa_git_core_ppa_saucy.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    68 sep 19 22:53 sbt.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    68 ene 16  2024 sbt.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    86 nov  4 20:05 sbt.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    86 nov  4 20:05 sbt.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   120 nov  4 20:05 shiftkey-packages.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   120 nov  4 20:05 shiftkey-packages.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    90 sep 19 22:53 spotify.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    50 ene 16  2024 spotify.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1812 nov  4 20:05 spotify.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1812 nov  4 20:05 spotify.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   121 sep 19 22:53 teams.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   121 ene 16  2024 teams.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1254 sep 19 22:53 teamviewer.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1112 sep  8  2022 teamviewer.list.dpkg-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1254 ene 16  2024 teamviewer.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   215 sep 19 22:53 termius.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   175 ene 16  2024 termius.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    86 nov  4 20:05 termius.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    86 nov  4 20:05 termius.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   100 nov  4 20:05 third-party.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   112 nov  4 20:05 third-party.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   266 sep 19 21:47 ubuntu-esm-apps.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   266 ene 16  2024 ubuntu-esm-apps.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   202 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu-esm-apps.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   202 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu-esm-apps.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   274 sep 19 21:47 ubuntu-esm-infra.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   274 ene 16  2024 ubuntu-esm-infra.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   206 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu-esm-infra.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   206 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu-esm-infra.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   129 sep 19 22:53 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-apps-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    91 ene 16  2024 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-apps-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   113 nov  4 20:05 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-apps-focal.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   113 nov  4 20:05 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-apps-focal.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   764 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   764 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   120 sep 19 22:53 ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   120 ene 16  2024 ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   695 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   695 nov  4 20:05 ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   108 sep 19 22:53 unityhub.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    70 ene 16  2024 unityhub.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   101 nov  4 20:05 unityhub.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   101 nov  4 20:05 unityhub.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   242 nov  4 20:13 vscode.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   114 nov  4 19:55 vscode.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    91 nov  4 20:05 vscode.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    91 nov  4 20:05 vscode.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   103 sep 19 22:53 webupd8team-java-raring.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   103 ene 16  2024 webupd8team-java-raring.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   113 nov  4 20:05 webupd8team-java-raring.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   113 nov  4 20:05 webupd8team-java-raring.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   110 sep 19 22:53 webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-raring.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   110 ene 16  2024 webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-raring.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   118 nov  4 20:05 webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-raring.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   118 nov  4 20:05 webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-raring.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   127 sep 19 22:53 yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    89 ene 16  2024 yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   698 nov  4 20:05 yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   698 nov  4 20:05 yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.sources.save

This is my sources.list.d directory. Also would need some advice as ive upgraded from 22.04 to make "some cleaning" of useless or outdated repos.
Thanks

any help please...im really stuck....
